# compute $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3.5........(2n-1)} -\frac{1}{3.5........(2n+1)})$

Tags: real-analysis

compute the summation

$\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3.5........(2n+1)}=  ?$

My attempts  : i take  $a_n =\frac{n}{3.5........(2n+1)}$

Now =$\frac{1}{2}$ .$\frac{(2n+ 1) - 1}{3.5........(2n+1)}= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3.5........(2n-1)} -\frac{1}{3.5........(2n+1)})$

after  that  i can not  able  to proceed  further,,,

pliz help me..

thanks  u

Comment: Write a partial sum, delete the parentheses, and look at consecutive terms.

Comment: im not getting @spiralstotheleft

Comment: A partial sum is $\sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3\cdot5...(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{3\cdot5...(2n+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3\cdot5...(2M+1)}$, which tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ since the last term tends to $0$. Therefore, the sum of your series is $\frac{1}{2}$. Note: Opening parenthesis before knowing that the partial sums converge, like it was done in your selected answer, is not justified. If you did it for another series like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-1)$ you get a series with a different character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work so far is good. Just keep going.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)} - \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n+1)}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{1\cdot 3} - \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} - \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7} + \cdots\right)$$

Comment: thanks u @ angryavian   can u  write ur answer as detail  as  in previous  question   ?  the value of ranks A., ImA  and Ker A

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compute $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3.5…(2n-1)} -\frac{1}{3.5…(2n+1)})$

You need to compute $\sum_{n=1}^K a_n$.

Which is $\frac 12(\frac 11 - \frac 13) + \frac 12(\frac 13-\frac 1{3\cdot 5})+.....+ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3.5…(2K-3)} -\frac{1}{3.5…(2K-1)}) + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3.5…(2K-1)} -\frac{1}{3.5…(2K+1)})$

And the compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n =\lim\limits_{K\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^K a_n$

====

Note:  If $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3.5…(2n-1)} -\frac{1}{3.5…(2n+1)})$ we can let $b_n =\frac{1}{3.5…(2n-1)}$

and then we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 12 (b_n - b_{n+1})$$.

And you should be able so solve that even if you don't have any frigging idea what $b_n$ was defined as.