# Prove that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac {n}{3.5.....(2n+1)} = {1\over 2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Apology if this is a duplicate question since I failed to figure that out.

I tried to make some telescoping things, couldn't make it so well.

After that I made it look something like  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac {n(2.4.......2n)}{2.3.4.5.....(2n+1)}$= $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac {2^n(n.n!)}{(2n+1)!}$
=$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac {2^n((n+1)n!-n!))}{(2n+1)!}$. Now it seems I have complexified the things.Any help?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{2n}{2n+1} = (1 - \frac{1}{2n+1})$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2871600/42969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $$\frac n{3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n + 1)}=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac 1 {3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n - 1)} - \frac 1{3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n + 1)}\right)$$ and the result is clear.

This technique is called [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).